# Requesting Data on Socket in C

Tags: c, sockets

In my C application, I wait for data on the socket in the following way:

```
printf("Opening socket and wait for data.\n");
while (i < 5)  
   while((connection_fd = accept(socket_fd, 
                            (struct sockaddr *) &address,
                            &address_length)) > -1)
   {
    bzero(buffer, 64);
    n = read(connection_fd,buffer,64);
    if (n < 0) printf("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("Here is the message of length %d bytes:\n\n", n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      printf("%02X", buffer[i]);
    } 
    printf("\n\n");          
    break;  
    }
 i++
 }
```

That means I read 5 times data from the Socket, however, by the looks of it I seem to be opening 5 different connections is that right? Is it possible to open the connection just once, keep it alive, and then check whether there is any data available on this connection?

Thanks, Patrick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code needs some restructuring, you should only accept once for each new connection:

```
while (1) {
    connection_fd = accept(socket_fd, ...);

    /* check for errors */
    if (connection_fd < 0) {
      /* handle error */
    }

    /* note this could block, if you don't want
       that use non-blocking I/O and select */    
    while ((n=read(connection_fd, buf, ...)) > 0) {
        /* do some work */
    }

    /* close fd */ 
    close(fd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. 
To do so you might like to exchange the arguments to the two `while()` loops:

```
while ((connection_fd = accept(socket_fd, 
                          (struct sockaddr *) &address,
                          &address_length)) > -1)
  while (i < 5)  
  {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Remove the `while (i<5)` bit. After the `read` you can read more data if required.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Move the statement calling accept function outside your loop and then call read using the same socket descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (n < 0) printf("ERROR reading from socket");
```

Why you are going ahead? either `break;` the loop or `continue;` for new connection.